# Convert null characters in Python strings to their literal characters

Tags: python-3.x, string, character-encoding

It's been a long time since I last used Python, I apologize if this is a dumb question.

I tried opening a Windows dump file with Python 3.9, but it couldn't detect the encoding, so I made it ignore any errors (`rfile = open('myfile', errors='ignore')`).

The resulting string (`string = rfile.read()`) contains characters such as `\x00` (null bytes) or other unicode characters starting with `\x` that Python didn't decode properly.

**My question is**: how can I convert these `\x12` characters to become literally `'\\' + 'x' + '1' + '2'`?

I need to know whenever `\x...` starts, but because `\x00` by itself is a character, `string.find('\\x')` doesn't find anything. I needed to first convert it to `'\\' + 'x' + '0' + '0'`

Comment: Id guess that _a Windows dump_ is a _binary file_ so use appropriate instruments e.g. [Debugging Tools for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/).

Comment: @JosefZ Thanks! I already looked at them, but all I need now is just a way to extract the ASCII characters. I can run an regex to do this, but I was legitimately curious as to whether it's possible to convert the string to literal `\ + x + 0 + 0`, like the console does